# File download using php include null values

Tags: php, csv, download

I have default csv template. I need to show this template when user click on a specific button.

The code is here

```
    $filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/content/formatted_blank.csv";
    $csvfile  = file_get_contents($filePath);
    $filename = "formatted_blank.csv";
    echo $csvfile;
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
    die();
```

The code is working fine. But the output file is not matching my default template. In default template I wrote header in 1 row, but download file showing in 7th row. There is white space rows coming.

Comment: Not sure if this will fix your issue but you want to always call `header()` *before* `echo`

Comment: Are there newlines in your template? Or do you maybe populate it with empty rows?

Comment: In my template only have one header. Nothing else

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `header` functions after `echo`. Make the oposite